Does DAPR support ActiveMQ Artemis?
Does DAPR support ActiveMQ Artemis? If not, what is solution to connect ActiveMQ Artemis?
Since ActiveMQ Artemis supports MQTT and DAPR also officially supports MQTT is it possible to use ActiveMQ Artemis with MQTT using DAPR?

ActiveMQ Artemis is a message broker which can serve as an integration point between systems and applications as long as those systems and applications use a supported protocol.
DAPR doesn't have to support ActiveMQ Artemis directly. If DAPR can use MQTT then it can use MQTT with ActiveMQ Artemis. That is the whole point of standardized protocols.

This worked using the MQTT acceptor in artemis.
